# ¿Por qué falla el procedimiento sp_rename con Msg 2812?

Tags: sql-server, tsql, sql-server-2017

Tengo un script que corremos desde hace varias versiones de SQL Server (creo que desde 2012) y que incluye modificar unas tablas:

```
-- The tables to be partitioned are renamed so they become backups
EXECUTE SP_RENAME cm_tabla1, cm_tabla1_bak;
EXECUTE SP_RENAME cm_tabla2, cm_tabla2_bak;
```

Como lo menciono, este script ha funcionado en MSSQL 2016 inclusive, sin errores.

Ahora, probándolo en MSSQL 2017, me da el siguiente error:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Server MYSERVER, Line 59
> Could not find stored procedure 'SP_RENAME'.
>
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Server MYSERVER, Line 60
> Could not find stored procedure 'SP_RENAME'.

Y no entiendo bien por qué rayos no funciona si ese es un SP del sistema, no lo creo yo.

Como lo indico, este script crea tablas, les pone datos, modifica las tablas y en el proceso renombra las que estaban para crear otra con el mismo nombre en algunos casos y poder copiar los datos, etc. Funcionó normalmente.

Este script también garantiza permisos de ejecución (las tablas están en una BD donde el usuario que ejecuta tiene GRANT CONTROL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de pelear mucho con permisos, revisar si el script PowerShell que corre todo estaba bien, o si el sqlcmd había cambiado, me dio por probar lo más simple al final. SSMS resaltaba el nombre del SP (`SP_RENAME`) como error.

Cambié ese código por

```
-- The tables to be partitioned are renamed so they become backups
EXECUTE sp_rename cm_tabla1, cm_tabla1_bak;
EXECUTE sp_rename cm_tabla2, cm_tabla2_bak;
```

Y ejecutó sin errores. Sale el warning de que *cambiar el nombre de cosas puede ser mala idea*, pero eso no es importante (ya sé que no estoy dañando nada, je). Conclusión: el *case* es importante para la instalación de MSSQL 2017 que tengo. Y ahí me fui a ver la configuración de la instancia de BD con más detalle.

Entonces, para cuando quieran evitar sufrimiento mental, elijan una de dos:

- Configuren la instancia con la variante `CI` del collation (case-insensitive) para que le dé igual que esté en mayúscula o minúscula el nombre de los SP del sistema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Usen la variante `CS` del collation (case-sensitive). Luego, pongan los llamados a los SP del sistema en minúscula. Idealmente, uno debería crear los SP propios con ese mismo estándar para evitar enredos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]